# Why can't I get variables from class()

Tags: python, class

```
class opponent(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        self.image = pygame.Surface ( (45, 80) )
        self.image.fill ( black)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect ()
        self.rect.y = height - 20
        self.rect.x = width / 2 + 300
        self.speedy = 0
        self.speedx = 0
        self.hitbox = (self.rect.x + 80, self.rect.y + 100, 80, 100)
        self.lives = 40
        self.max_lives = 40
        self.health_length = 100
        self.health_ratio = self.max_lives / self.health_length
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__ ( self )

def op1_health_bar():
    pygame.draw.rect ( screen, (255, 0, 0),(opponent.rect.x - 30, opponent.rect.top - 50, opponent.lives / opponent.health_ratio, 25) )
    pygame.draw.rect ( screen, (255, 255, 255), (opponent.rect.x - 30, opponent.rect.top - 50, opponent.health_length, 25),4 )
```

For some reason I can't make the function view the class, also this isn't the full code just the code with the opponent.

Comment: `rect` is an object attribute. Therefore you need to create an instance object of the class.

Comment: Side note: should the `op1_health_bar` function be a part of the `opponent` class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create an object that is an INSTANCE of that class:

```
class Opponent(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        self.image = pygame.Surface ( (45, 80) )
        self.image.fill ( black)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect ()
        self.rect.y = height - 20
        self.rect.x = width / 2 + 300
        self.speedy = 0
        self.speedx = 0
        self.hitbox = (self.rect.x + 80, self.rect.y + 100, 80, 100)
        self.lives = 40
        self.max_lives = 40
        self.health_length = 100
        self.health_ratio = self.max_lives / self.health_length
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__ ( self )

opponent = Opponent()

def op1_health_bar():
    pygame.draw.rect ( screen, (255, 0, 0),(opponent.rect.x - 30, opponent.rect.top - 50, opponent.lives / opponent.health_ratio, 25) )
    pygame.draw.rect ( screen, (255, 255, 255), (opponent.rect.x - 30, opponent.rect.top - 50, opponent.health_length, 25),4 )
```